# git diff show all changes between two commits

Tags: git

Lets say I have 100 commits and I want to see all the changes of a specific file.

```
git diff 0..100 -- file
```

This only gives me the changes of the file between the commits. But what I really want, is to be shown all the changes that were made. Eg. also those in commit 25, 36, 67 etc.

Is there a neat git command for this or do I have to make a script?
I guess I want git to do something like the following:

```
git diff 0..1, 1..2, 2..3 etc... -- file
```

Though I don't want to have to type out all the different commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to use `git show`?

```
$ git show 0..100 -- file
commit 100
Author: ...
Date:   ...

    Commit Message

diff --git ... ...
...

commit 99
Author: ...
Date:   ...

...
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar `git log -p 0..100 -- file` answer, but both work, so let's just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that as well, I just really like `git show`.

Comment: Indeed. Underrated git command, I agree.

Comment: Interestingly, `git show` and `git log -p` are *almost* the same command. The big difference is that `git log` has `--walk` enabled by default and `git show` has `--no-walk`. However, `git log` also *doesn't* have `--cc` turned on by default, while `git show` does, so they show merge commits differently as well.

Comment: Well, that, and, `git show` handles a lot more special cases, such as extracting one file from an old commit (`git show a123456:path/to/file`). [oh and @RomainValeri]

Comment: What happens in the case when file named has changed from, say `a` (in commit 0) to say, `b`(in commit 100)?